# Putting millions of items in a QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a list of 2,888,991 channel objects. Each object has a name and a sample rate. I am trying to put them into a QTreeView. Each channel name is split on ':' '-' and '_'. If the name is H1:IOP-LSC0_DCU_ID and the sample rate is 16.0 then it should go into the tree as:

```
H1
    IOP
        LSC0
            H1:IOP-LSC0_DCU_ID 16.0
```

The split name is in the first column and the sample rate is in the second column.

I have code that seems to accomplish this, but it takes a prohibitive amount of time to run. I am looking for suggestions on improving it, especially the speed.

The code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QStyleFactory, QTreeView, QTableView, QListView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

import nds2
import sys
import re


def find_or_add_and_return(parent, text_list):
    parent.setColumnCount(2)

    item_list = [QStandardItem(text) for text in text_list]

    # If the list has a length less than 2, then elements are appended until the list has a length of 2.
    # If the list has a length greater than 2, then all but the first 2 items are truncated.
    item_list.extend([QStandardItem()] * 2)
    item_list = item_list[0:2]

    assert (len(item_list) == parent.columnCount())
    for r in range(parent.rowCount()):
        if item_list[0].text() == parent.child(r, 0).text() and item_list[1].text() == parent.child(r, 1).text():
            return parent.child(r, 0)

    parent.appendRow(item_list)
    return parent.child(parent.rowCount() - 1, 0)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        tree_view_model = QStandardItemModel()

        parent_item = tree_view_model.invisibleRootItem()


        conn = nds2.connection('h1nds1', 8088)
        channel_list = conn.find_channels()

        for channel in channel_list:
            text_list_list = [[x] for x in re.split('[:\-_]', channel.name, 3)]
            text_list_list[-1] = [channel.name, str(channel.sample_rate)]

            parent = parent_item
            for text_list in text_list_list:
                parent = find_or_add_and_return(parent, text_list)


        tree_view = QTreeView()
        tree_view.setHeaderHidden(True)
        tree_view.header().setSectionResizeMode(3) # QHeaderView::ResizeToContents
        tree_view.setModel(tree_view_model)


        layout.addWidget(tree_view)


        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


app = QApplication([])

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT: This code seems faster:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QStyleFactory, QTreeView, QTableView, QListView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

import nds2
import sys
import re


class TrieNode():
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.child_dict = {}
        self.item = item

    def insert(self, text_list, data):
        parent = self

        for text in text_list:
            if text in parent.child_dict:
                parent = parent.child_dict[text]
            else:
                item_list = [QStandardItem(text), QStandardItem()]
                parent.item.appendRow(item_list)
                parent.child_dict[text] = TrieNode(item_list[0])
                parent = parent.child_dict[text]

        parent.item.appendRow([QStandardItem(data[0]), QStandardItem(data[1])])


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        tree_view_model = QStandardItemModel()

        parent_item = tree_view_model.invisibleRootItem()


        conn = nds2.connection('h1nds1', 8088)
        channel_list = conn.find_channels()

        t = TrieNode(parent_item)

        for channel in channel_list:
            text_list = re.split('[:\-_]', channel.name, 5)
            del text_list[-1]

            t.insert(text_list, [channel.name, str(channel.sample_rate)])


        tree_view = QTreeView()
        tree_view.setHeaderHidden(True)
        tree_view.header().setSectionResizeMode(3) # QHeaderView::ResizeToContents
        tree_view.setModel(tree_view_model)

        layout.addWidget(tree_view)


        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


app = QApplication([])

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I can't really help you with PyQt, but I can tell you that the secret to making a large tree like this is to NOT enumerate everything.  Instead, build only the root level, and then fill in each level as it is expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is more structure to your data than you are reporting.

## Micro-optimizations

At the detail level, is it possible that there is a structure other than "delimited by :, -, _" to the names? Could the first field be always 2 characters? Are any of the subfields constant length? Do the delimiters always appear in a specific order?

If you have subfields of a constant width, you can use a slice instead of a regex to extract them. It's a *lot* faster to say

```
f1 = name[0:2] 
f2 = name[3:6]
f3 = name[7:11]
```

rather than

```
f = re.split(r'[-:_]', name)
```

Alternatively, some fields may be variable length, but if you can count on the sequence of delimiters you might be able to do something like this using [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20partition#str.partition):

```
f1, _, rest = name.partition(':')
f2, _, rest = rest.partition('-')
f3, _, rest = rest.partition('_')
```

Using "string methods" instead of "regex methods" is frequently (but **not** always) faster.

## Macro-optimizations

Can you "step back" from the problem and find a higher-level approach that would give better performance?

In particular, I would suggest looking for a function or method in the `nds2` interface that allows you to extract some of the prefix data without pulling all the names.

### Caching

If you can't get the data from the API, you should first submit a bug/enhancement/issue to the API guys explaining what you are doing and what support you *wish* you could get from them. They might be happy to add a call that would solve your problem for you.

If not, consider building a local data structure **not** part of the Qt tree, and caching it.

For example, you have a tree of prefixes. Convert that into a tree of dictionaries, and serialize it. You could create a user-local cache using `pickle` or if the data only rarely changes you might just create a `json` or `toml` file and ship it with your package.

If you could get the first three levels of the tree stored as json, and if new high-level identifiers only appeared once a year when the budget expanded, you could do your updates manually.

Alternatively, you might be able to perform a query, or have the API guys add a query, that let you ask "are there any channel objects that don't match these first3 tree prefixes?"

### Late Querying

Especially in combination with caching, or a pre-built tree, above, @DavidG's suggestion to only build the parts of the tree you need makes *huge* amounts of sense. Why transfer 2+ million records when you only need to list 100?

I couldn't find a `nds2` package on pypi, but I did see one called `nds2utils`. That package appears to support some kind of globbing for channel names, so I assume you can do a similar thing?

Just query for `f"{tree0}:{tree1}-{tree2}*"` and you can get the values you need for the subtree below tree1/tree2/tree3. Hopefully that's something you can get fast enough to keep the interface snappy.